# getting incompability of protobuf while install grpcio-tools

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, grpc

when I want to install grpcio-tools using command :

```
python3 -m pip install grpcio-tools
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

while on the other hand when I want to run pip3 install mysql-connector-python to install mysql-connector-python:
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

what should I do for this incompability?

```
whereis protoc
protoc: /usr/local/bin/protoc


 pip show protobuf
 Name: protobuf
 Version: 3.20.1
 Summary: Protocol Buffers
 Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
 Author: None
 Author-email: None
 License: BSD-3-Clause
 Location: /home/lfathi/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
 Requires: 
 Required-by: mysql-connector-python, grpcio-tools

protoc --version
 libprotoc 3.2.0
```

which causes problem in running grpc
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ15N.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LXpM1.png

Comment: `mysql-connector-python` does not require `protobuf` as a dependency. Do you have any config for dependency management, or are you installing these globally?

Comment: @JishanShaikh that is true there should not be dependency, No I dont install globally I followed : https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/

Comment: You sure you've the prerequisites installed? Btw `protobuf-python` latest is 4.21, maybe try updating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql-connector-python` **does** appear to require `protobuf`:

```bash
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
python3 -m pip install mysql-connector-python==8.0.31
python3 -m pip freeze
```

Yields:

```
mysql-connector-python==8.0.31
protobuf==3.20.1
```

Or `/path/to/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mysql_connector_python-8.0.31.dist-info/METADATA`

```
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Name: mysql-connector-python
Version: 8.0.31
Summary: MySQL driver written in Python
Home-page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html
Author: Oracle and/or its affiliates
Author-email: 
License: GNU GPLv2 (with FOSS License Exception)
Download-URL: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/
Keywords: mysql db
Platform: UNKNOWN
[edited]
Requires-Dist: protobuf (<=3.20.1,>=3.11.0)
[edited]
```

Google made [breaking changes to the Python implementation of Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06#python-updates) between 3.20.1 and 4.20.1.

You need to find a `grpcio-tools` release that uses `<=3.20.1`. Curiously, [`1.46.0`](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio-tools/1.46.0/) should work (03-May-2022) as it's beween `protobuf` `3.20.1` (21-Apr-2022) and `3.20.2` (13-Sep-2022) but, this also fails.

Please try:

```
python3 -m pip install mysql-connector-python==8.0.31
python3 -m pip install grpcio-tools==1.44.0

python3 -m pip freeze
```

Yields:

```
grpcio==1.51.1
grpcio-tools==1.44.0
mysql-connector-python==8.0.31
protobuf==3.20.3
```

Please don't use screenshots in stack overflow questions when it is possible to copy-and-paste the text instead. Using images inhibits the ability for others to copy-and-paste content to help answer questions and there's no guarantee that the images will last as long as the questions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error trying to build a container image. It errored at `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` with the below:

```
ERROR: Cannot install grpcio-status==1.53.0, mysql-connector-python==8.0.32 and protobuf==4.22.1 
because these package versions have conflicting dependencies

    grpcio-status 1.53.0 depends on protobuf>=4.21.6
    mysql-connector-python 8.0.32 depends on protobuf<=3.20.3 and >=3.11.0

    To fix this you could try to:
    1. loosen the range of package versions you have specified
    2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
```

Removing the package version (as in suggested fix 2) solved the problem for me.

- `requirements.txt` (dependencies with package versions):

```
grpcio-status==1.53.0
mysql-connector-python==8.0.32
protobuf==4.22.1
```

- I solved the problem by removing the package versions:

```
grpcio-status
mysql-connector-python
protobuf
```

Alternatively, install the packages together as below. Pip will attempt to solve the conflict:

```
pip install mysql-connector-python grpcio-tools protobuf
```